# How to call javascript functions of external files from ejs template?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I have this file to add a new Ship and the script to populate de fleet dropdown menu works fine:

**new.ejs file:**

```
<% include ../partials/header %>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">Create a new Ship</h1>
        <div style="width: 30%; margin: 25px auto;">
            <form action="/ships" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" name="tons" placeholder="tons" min="0" step="1">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="image" placeholder="img url">
                </div>
                <!--<div class="form-group">-->
                <!--    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="fleet" placeholder="fleet">-->
                <!--</div>-->

                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" type="text" name="fleet" id="selectNumber" placeholder="fleet">
                        <option>Choose a fleet</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <script>
                    var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");
                    var options = ["First fleet", "Second fleet", "Metropolitan fleet", "Support fleet"];
                    for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                        var opt = options[i];
                        var el = document.createElement("option");
                        el.textContent = opt;
                        el.value = opt;
                        select.appendChild(el);
                    }
                </script>




                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="description" placeholder="description">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Submit!</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <a href="/ships/">Back</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>


<% include ../partials/footer %>
```

I want to separate the "logic" from the view, so I need to create a file:
**../public/js/jsscripts.js**

and I guess inside the jsscripts.js

```
module.exports = {
  PopulateFleet: function () {
var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");
                    var options = ["First fleet", "Second fleet", "Metropolitan fleet", "Support fleet"];
                    for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                        var opt = options[i];
                        var el = document.createElement("option");
                        el.textContent = opt;
                        el.value = opt;
                        select.appendChild(el);
                    }

};
```

**1) Do I need to require the file "jsscripts" from my app.js ?**
Something like:

```
jscripts= require ("./public/js/jscripts");
```

**2) How to call the function "PopulateFleet" from the new.ejs file?**
something like??

```
<% PopulateFleet %>
```

or

```
<% jscripts.PopulateFleet %>
```

**Folder structure**

Fleet - public - js -> **jsscripts.js**

Fleet - views - ships -> **- new.ejs**

Comment: use <% jscripts.PopulateFleet() %>

Comment: Thanks for the help by I get the error "jsTools is not defined"  on the ejs file

Using: var jsTools   = require("./public/js/jscripts");

on the app.js file

Comment: "You can´t" say this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47001537/how-to-include-external-js-file-to-ejs-node-template-page

Comment: Is your newejs file in public folder? Can you show me your folder structure?

Comment: Added at the bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue and I find a solution.
So I know this solution is not the ideal solution but it's works.

I have a function's file "my_functions.js" with code like that :

```
var processSomething = function(variableXXXX)
{
    ...
    ...
    return(variableNew)
}

module.exports.processSomething     = processSomething;
```

I require this file into "application.js" like that :

```
var myFonctions = require('./include/my_fonctions.js');
```

And I pass this variable to my EJS like that

```
res.render('view.ejs',{myFonctionsForEjs:myFonctions});
```

And, in my EJS File I can do that

```
var response = myFonctionsForEjs.processSomething(1234);
```

Answer (score 1):

`use <%= jscripts.PopulateFleet() %>`

Comment: I'm using C9 as online IDE, and the require line only works with
`jscripts   = require ("./public/js/jsscripts");`

but still I get the error "jscripts is not defined" on the new.ejs file

Comment: i am pretty sure you are not including the file correctly=> try this .. require ("../../../public/js/jsscripts");

Comment: I tryed the first time I read your answer and I get error when runining node app.js "Error: Cannot find module '../../../public/js/jsscripts'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)" But with ./public/js/jsscripts runs ok. The problem is calling javascript on the ejs template

Comment: Even is I play withe ejs playground on: https://ionicabizau.github.io/ejs-playground/ a line like `<% alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!!"); %>` runs OK, but not on the ejs on node.

Comment: Hmm I am not able to figure out your error. Could you send me a codesandbox or jsfiddle link? Whichever is convinient

Comment: Here you have the complete "app" http://www.filedropper.com/imperialfleet
It's based con YelpCamp https://ide.c9.io/learnwithcolt/webdevbootcamp

Comment: Path looks fine. Just a silly mistake. i missed a "=". Updated my answer. Check this and use '-' or '=' according to your requirement. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48522768/the-difference-between-and-in-ejs

Comment: I really appreciate your help but still not working. If I try the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50124742/how-to-include-a-js-script-in-a-ejs-file-nodejs-app using   <script src="jscripts.PopulateFleet()"></script> the app get frozen on the page (waiting forever for the script) but at least I didn't recieve any error on the console.

I will keep looking for a solution. Thanks a lot.